# How do I add 30 to this form field value?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
    $('#input_hours1').keyup(function() {
      $('#input_hours2').val($('#input_hours1').val()); 
    });

    $('#input_minutes1').keyup(function() {
      $('#input_minutes2').val($('#input_minutes1').val()); 
    });
```

So basically I have 4 input boxes:

> 2 for starting time(hour, minutes)
>
> 2 for ending time(hour, minutes)

The code above copies the starting values to the end values.

How do I add 30 to the ending date minutes input box (`#input_minutes2`) and increment the `#input_hours2` in case `#input_minutes2` is 31 or bigger? Could someone add a jsFiddle?

For example:

```
Starting time hour : 1
Starting time minutes: 31
Ending time hour :2
Ending time minutes: 01
```

---

```
Startimg time hour: 1

Starting time minutes: 30

Ending time hour: 2

Ending time minutes: 00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really quite simple logic just implementing an `if` to detect whether we need to increment the hour at all.  You will need to `validate` incase the user adds `text` as opposed to digits.

```
$('#input_hours1, #input_minutes1').keyup(function () {
    startHours = parseInt($('#input_hours1').val(), 10);
    startMinutes = parseInt($('#input_minutes1').val(), 10);
    if (startMinutes >= 30) {
        endHours = startHours + 1;
        endMinutes = startMinutes - 30;
    } else {
        endHours = startHours;
        endMinutes = startMinutes + 30;
    }
    $('#input_hours2').val(endHours);
    $('#input_minutes2').val(endMinutes);
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/4uR2W/

Comment: I have a small problem with the code above. If I enter 9:30...I get the end time 9:60 and not 10. Any way to fix this? I tried ..if(startMinutes =>30) {..} but it doesn't seem to work anymore if I do that. And by the way, thanks for taking your time to help me out.

Comment: Ah yes, that is correct, you need to write `>=` as opposed to `=>` have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The one using pure JS:

```
<html>
<script>
    function getm()
    {
        var smin=document.getElementById('smin').value;
        var ssec=document.getElementById('ssec').value;
        for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        {   
            if(ssec==59)
            {
                ssec=0;
                smin++;
            }
            else
            ssec++;
        }
        document.getElementById('emin').value=smin;
        document.getElementById('esec').value=ssec;
    }
</script>
<body>

Start Time: <input type="text" id="smin" onkeyup=getm()><input type="text" id="ssec"onkeyup=getm()></br>
End Time: <input type="text" id="emin" ><input type="text" id="esec">
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nive00/DL7A6/2/)

the one using jquery:

```
<html>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var hours;
var mins;
function calc()
    {

        for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        {   
            if(mins==59)
            {
                mins=0;
                hours++;
            }
            else
            mins++;
        }

    }
$('#input_hours1').keyup(function() {

    hours=$('#input_hours1').val();
    mins=$('#input_minutes1').val();
    calc();
      $('#input_hours2').val(hours); 
      $('#input_minutes2').val(mins);  
    });

    $('#input_minutes1').keyup(function() {
      mins=$('#input_minutes1').val();
      hours=$('#input_hours1').val();
        calc();
        $('#input_hours2').val(hours); 
      $('#input_minutes2').val(mins);  
    });
});

</script>
<body>

Start Time: <input type="text" id="input_hours1"><input type="text" id="input_minutes1"></br>
End Time: <input type="text" id="input_hours2" ><input type="text" id="input_minutes2">
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nive00/DL7A6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `parseInt()` method to convert string to integer. here is the [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nV4y8/1/)

```
 $('#input_minutes1').change(function() {debugger;
        var inputmin=$('#input_minutes1').val();
        if(parseInt(inputmin)>=30){
            $('#input_hours2').val(parseInt($('#input_hours1').val())+1);
            var minutes= parseInt($('#input_minutes1').val())+30;
            if(minutes>=60)
                $('#input_minutes2').val(minutes-60);
       }
        else{
        $('#input_hours2').val($('#input_hours1').val());
            $('#input_minutes2').val(parseInt($('#input_minutes1').val())+30);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Could you please add a jsFiddle? I'm not entirely sure how to do this...I just started out with jquery/javascript.

Comment: added fiddle, please verify your requirement